Inequalities related to probabilities
Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables taking values in $\{-2, 1\}$ with $P(X_1=1)=2/3$ and $P(X_1=-2)=1/3$. Denote $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i.$ I want to show that there is a constant $C$, independent of $n$, such that
$$
P(S_n\geq \sqrt{n \ln n})\leq \frac{C}{(\ln n)^{3/2}}.
$$
Now, I have worked out $\mathbb E(S_n) =0$ and $Var(S_n)=2n$. By Chebyshev's inequality, I only can obtain the upper bound of $\frac{C}{\ln n}$, but not of order $(\ln n)^{-3/2}$. I am wondering what kind of trick needs to be applied here. I was looking at possibilities of applying Chernoff bounds but that usually will end up with an exponential term on the right. I would be delighted if anyone could share some insights here.

Applying Chebyshev's exponential inequality for $x_{n}=\sqrt{ n\ln n }$ and any $t > 0$ we get
$$
\mathbb{P}(S_n\geq x_{n})\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}e^{ tS_{n} }}{e^{ tx_{n} }} =: p_{n}.
$$
Calculate it
$$
p_{n} = e^{ -t\sqrt{ n\ln n } }\left( \frac{1}{3}e^{ t }+\frac{2}{3}e^{ -2t } \right)^{n}.
$$
For $0<t < 1$ we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
e^{ t } &<& 1 +t+2t^{2},
\\
e^{ -2t } &<& 1 -2t+2t^{2}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
We can take $t_n = \frac{3}{2} \frac{\ln \ln n}{\sqrt{ n\ln n }} < 1$, then
$$
p_{n} \le  \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{3/2}}(1+2t^{2})^{n} \le \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{3/2}}\left( 1+\frac{4.5}{n} \right)^{n} \le \frac{e^{ 4.5 }}{(\ln n)^{3/2}}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\mathbb{P}(S_{n}\ge\sqrt{ n\ln n })\le \frac{C}{(\ln n)^{3/2}}.
$$
